# How do I match a nested bracket and brace pair while ignoring single instances using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Given lines such as:

```
[{ ERR }]
 { ABC }
 [ NT1 ]

 [ XYZ }  <- This is an illegal form and should also be ignored
```

How do I write a regex that will capture the first segment, but ignore the others if I read line by line. So if there is one nested *pair* of [] and one *pair* of {} it will match that, and then not match on the other lines.

I've attempted to do this using the expression `([ \[]*([ \{]*[a-zA-Z]+[ \} ]*)[ \] ]*)`

I'm also trying to output the three alphanumerics in the center as a match subgroup (there will never be more than three char). Whitespace is irrelevant.

Comment: How nested can they be? `[{[{XYZ}]}]` possible? What about `[{ABC}{XYZ}]`? Also, are you trying to match `{ABC}` or just the contents `ABC`? Are you performing a replace?

Comment: @ctwheels [{ ABC }] is what I am looking for. They will be more nested in larger groups of already nested segments, but that's something I'd like to tackle on my own once I get a better grasp of the regex. Thanks

Comment: I think you want `\[\{.*\}\]`?

Comment: As it stands, `\[{[^}]*}]` works for your given samples

Comment: @Aran-Fey That was quick. Thanks - regex is not my strong point.

Comment: @Aran-Fey that can give unexpected results. Test against `[{ABC}] some random text here [{XYZ}]`

Comment: I've modified @Aran-Fey answer to output the center alphanumerics as a subgroup : `\[\{(.*)\}\]`

Comment: Use `r'\[\{(.*?)}]'`